# How to upload a json file to the github repository?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, github

please help with github.I upload my website to the github repository. I have a json file with a translation that is processed in javascript locally, everything works, but not on github. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you check your `.gitignore` file?

Comment: Did you run `git add lang.json` and `git commit`, `git push`?

Comment: Yes, my.gitignore is empty, but still json is not displayed

Comment: Did you run the above commands ? Or you can add me to your repo, if you don't mind.  dreambold is my username on github

Comment: @DreamBold I added you to my repository. I'll be glad if it helps, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you upload a static website to GitHub Pages, it takes a while to load up. Make sure you have also configured the DNS settings correctly on both the Github repository settings and on your domain. Your respository must also have a CNAME file on the root directory with the name of your Website.

Comment: But I don't have a domain. I checked only locally using XMLHttpRequest to use json.